# How to set GCC_COLORS in gcc4.9 to emit colorizing diagnostics messages?

Tags: linux, gcc, terminal, g++

[gcc4](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html).9 supports the colorizing diagnostics for compiler warning/error messages.

We can enable it for a particular program using the option "`fdiagnostics-color`". Currently I am using gcc4.9.1 and I append this particular option in my makefile as follows:

```
CC = /home/mantosh/gcc-4.9.1/bin/g++ -std=c++1y -Wall -pthread
DFLAG = -g -gdwarf-2 -fdiagnostics-color=always
OUTFILE = test

$(OUTFILE): test.cpp
    $(CC) $(DFLAG) -o $(OUTFILE) test.cpp

clean: 
    rm -f *.o $(OUTFILE)
```

If I compile a *.cpp file a get the following nice coloured message. This is really great feature added by GCC.

[image]

While reading the GCC offical link, it seems that this setting can *permanently  enabled* using the GCC environmental variable ***"GCC_COLORS"***.

Could somebody explains how to set/change/customize this particular environment variable?

I am using Ubuntu12.04/GCC4.9.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just add this line to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'
```

You can then reload it with `source ~/.bashrc` so you don't have to logout/login.

Comment: the way I read it setting the `GCC_COLORS` variable only changes the colors, but setting it will not set `-fdiagnostics-color=always` which would be desirable on e.g. a CI server   (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Language-Independent-Options.html)

Comment: setting `GCC_COLORS` to a non-empty string implies `-fdiagnostic-color=auto`, this works when `stderr` is on the terminal, otherwise you must pass `-fdiagnostic-color` to the compiler; the colors string I wrote is the default one used by gcc

Comment: @gengisdave This is sometimes not possible, especially on a CI server that launch build tools like `rpmbuild` that reset everything. It could be nice to be able to enable it globally.