# GCC_COLORS in combination with ccache

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning, ccache

I am using gcc 4.9.2 with ccache 3.1.10. My shell environment contains `GCC_COLORS=auto` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070873/how-to-set-gcc-colors-in-gcc4-9-to-emit-colorizing-diagnostics-messages); tried `yes` and `always` too).

As a minimal test I compile this `main.c` file

```c
int main() {
    int a;
    return 0;
}
```

with `gcc -c main.c -Wall -o main.o` and observe (as desired)

```text
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:2:7: warning: unused variable ‘a’ [-Wunused-variable]
   int a;
       ^
```

with `main.c:` and `main.c:2:7:`, `‘main’:` and `‘a’` in bold face, the `^` in boldface green, and the `warning:` in magenta bold face.

Compiling with `ccache` the colorisation disappears.

NB: `ccache gcc -Wall -c main.c -o main.o` is colorless, but `ccache gcc -Wall main.c -o main` remains colored.

NB2: `ccache gcc -Wall -c main.c -o main.o -fdiagnostics-color` also preserves colors in the output.

Question: Is there a recommended way to have the `export GCC_COLORS` functionality with `ccache`? I'd prefer to have colors globally enabled (as through the `~/.MYSHELLrc`) and without adding `-fdiagnostics-color` globally to `$CFLAGS`[0] and I want to avoid [custom wrappers](https://github.com/pseyfert/gcc-color) which parse the output messages (and might get confused with `LC_MESSAGES` settings).

[0]: I have many `Makefiles` which don't add their config to `CFLAGS` but overwrite the environment settings.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure it's relevant anymore, but I just tested with `GCC_COLORS=yes` with ccache version 3.4.1 and gcc 7.4.0 and that seems to work fine for me. I had the same issue when `GCC_COLORS` wasn't set.